# Unit Testing involving databases

Tags: python, unit-testing

Suppose I have a directory

```
  home/user/my_python_scripts/
                   /src
                       /my_script.py
                   /tests
                      /test_my_script.py
```

I am running some unit tests to test `my_script.py` from the `~/my_python_scripts/test` directory. I am importing the function from `my_script` in to my `test_my_script.py`.

The problem however arises since the function in `my_script.py` imports two other functions from another script. Those two functions query a database for specific data. I am mocking and patching these two functions in my test script however when I run `pytest` on this script the function ends up querying the database regardless. I looked at the two functions that `my_script.py` uses. Each of them queries a different database and furthermore one of the functions ends up using three other functions that live in the same file as it does.

Am I not accounting for these functions and/or database properly in my unit test? I cannot share the code since it is proprietary but I am more than happy to share my unit test code below:

```
from pytest_mock import mocker

params = [(3141, 55)]
raw_data = [{'a': 'fizz', 'b': 'buzz', 'c': 'foo', 'd': 'hello'}]
descriptors = ['taxi', 3141, 55, 1]

def test_get_data(mocker):
    setattr(get_data, 'get_raw_data', params)
    mocker.patch.object(get_data, 'get_raw_data')
    get_data.get_raw_data.return_value = params
    setattr(get_data, 'get_data_by_day', raw_data)
    mocker.patch.object(get_data, 'get_data_by_day')
    get_data.get_data_by_day.return_value = raw_data
    assert get_data('taxi', 3141, '1', '3') == raw_data, descriptors
```

Looking for any advice as well as tips.

Comment: This sounds rather like a design problem. **importing** should not trigger real actions.

Comment: so you're saying the way the two other functions were designed are flawed. regardless of that, do you have any advice about how to proceed in this scenario, besides rewriting all that other code.

Comment: I am not that much into python; so, no. But again; do you really want that an import statement triggers such activities? What if somebody has such an import by accident in his script? Copy and paste happens all the time. So, in my eyes, the only reasonable, long term answer is to fix the real problem; instead working around it; even in your test setup.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will address the problem accordingly.

Comment: But still, interesting question ... time for your upvote. I hate it when my (most often great ;-) questions dont get upvoted, so told myself to be less shy about upvoting myself ...

Comment: @GhostCat I figured it out I was patching the functions but then I wasn't using the correct functions to set the values. After I changed the `return_values` to the mocked functions everything worked as intended. Thanks for the up vote!

Comment: @GhostCat yes I provided an updated answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out. I was not correctly setting the values on the patched mock functions. This is the code that ended up working properly.

```
from mock import patch
from .relative.path import get_data

params = [(3141, 55)]
raw_data = [{'a': 'fizz', 'b': 'buzz', 'c': 'foo', 'd': 'hello'}]
descriptors = ['taxi', 3141, 55, 1]

@patch.object(get_data, 'get_raw_data')
@patch.object(get_data, 'get_data_by_day')
def test_get_stuff_1(mock_get_data_by_day, mock_get_raw_data):
    mock_get_data_by_day.return_value = raw_data
    mock_get_raw_data.return_value = params
    result = get_data.get_stuff('taxi', 3141, '1', '3')
    assert result == (raw_data, descriptors)
```

I import the script `get_data.py` as an object, and then patch each function `get_raw_data` and `get_data_by_day` as attributes of this object. Then when I run the unit test on the mock values I provide it returns the results I expect.